# How to crop an image getting from android resource folder(@mipmap)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, crop

I have an image view pager which will select an image.But i want to crop this image with zoomIn and ZoomOut function in image.How I can do this?

```
mImageCaptureUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://app.islamic.unikacomp.myapplication/" +sliderImagesId[num]);
// Retrieve a WallpaperManager
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(Animalwallpaper.this);         
try {
// Change the current system wallpaper
myWallpaperManager.setResource(sliderImagesId[num]);
// Show a toast message on successful change
Toast.makeText(Animalwallpaper.this,"Wallpaper successfully changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: show us what you've done so far ? So that we can suggest you some ways to your goal

Comment: I think you can search and use some image croping library and pinch joom functionality from github.

Comment: i searched.but can't find

Comment: For zoom functionality refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/ and for croping refer this https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView

Comment: Thank you.i will test and giving my feedback

Comment: for better understading first of all implement crop functionality and after that implement zooming functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple library on Github 
Here are the few-

[Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/)

[Croper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/)

Comment: i will try and reply